# Explanation of Lemma on meta cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

I am studying the article ["INFINITE METACYCLIC GROUPS AND THEIR
NON-ABELIAN TENSOR SQUARES"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/0D30B7739065E8B6C46C0AF81C9859AC/S0013091500021258a.pdf/infinite-metacyclic-groups-and-their-non-abelian-tensor-squares.pdf). In this article authors have proved a lemma, (Lemma 3.1):

> Lemma 3.1. Let $m,n, r$ be integers with $m,n$ non-negative, $\gcd(r,m)=1$, and let
> $$G = \langle a,b \mid a^m = b^n = 1, bab^{-1} = a^{r}\rangle,$$
> a split metacyclic group. Then every $g\in G$ can be written as $g = a^\alpha b^\beta$, where $\alpha ,\beta$ are integers which are unique modulo $m$ and $n$, respectively. If $h \in G$ with $h = a^\gamma b^\delta$, then we have the following multiplication, conjugation formulae in $G$:
>
> 1. $gh = a^{\alpha+\gamma r^{\delta}}b^{\beta+\delta}$
> 2. $^g h$ = $a^{\gamma(1-r^\beta)+\alpha r^{\gamma}}b^{\beta}$

The authors gave a very short proof. When I am trying to prove the part (2) of the lemma I am getting some mistakes. Like take $g = a^\alpha b^\beta$ and $h=a$ or $h=b$, then I think the formula fails.

I want to prove the second part of the lemma, here $^gh=ghg^{-1}$. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, both equations are wrong - the authors have been careless. I make it
$$gh = a^{\alpha +\gamma r^\beta}b^{\beta+\delta}$$
$$ghg^{-1} = a^{\alpha(1-r^{\delta})+ \gamma r^\beta} b^\delta.$$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.